# separate string input from text file java

Tags: java, arrays

I'm a java beginner and I have a small question about scanning from a text file
Suppose I have a text file like this

```
abc
012
4g5
(0 0 0)
(0 1 3)
(1 2 6)
(1 1 0)
abcde
blahblah
```

Now I want to make an array for ONLY the string inside the parenthesis, meaning that how to tell the scanner to scan only the strings started from the first open parentheses, reset the array input after the following right parentheses, and eventually stop scanning after the last right parentheses. This is what I have so far:

*for the array, it will take the first digit as the row#, second digit as the col# and the third digit as the value

```
while (file.hasNext()) {
    if (file.next().equals("(")) {
        do {
            2Darray[Integer.parseInt(file.next())][Integer.parseInt(file.next())] = file.next(); 

        }
        while (!file.next().equals(")"));
}
```

thanks

Comment: That loop will run for every row element, creating a new array each time

Comment: You should use `Scanner.nextLine()` method to read each line. And then apply appropriate test on them.

Comment: Updated my answer. Found and tested a new regex. Good luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend you used [RegEx](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) to match your parameters.

Have to mention that **file** in below case is a `BufferedReader`. [Document yourself on that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5868369/how-to-read-a-large-text-file-line-by-line-in-java).

```
while ((line = file.readLine()) != null)
{
    if( line.matches("\\((.*?)\\)") ) // Match string between two parantheses  
    {
         String trimmedLine = line.subString(1, line.length - 1); // Takes the string without parantheses
         String[] result = trimmedLine.split(" "); // Split at white space   
    }
}

// result[0] is row#
// result[1] is col#
// result[2] is value
```

A flaw in this code is that you **must** respect the text line formatting as you mentioned in your question (e.g. `"(3 5 6)"`).

Comment: Thanks for the help, however I get error at this "(?<=\()(.*?)(?=\))" invalid escape sequence, I removed the 2's \ \ the error is gone but nothing happened when i ran it. And for the next.split, isn't it line.split? cause there is no next.split

Comment: No no no. You don't remove the slashes, you escape them. I've edited my answer; copy the new regex.

Comment: And yes, you are right. It's not `next`. It's `trimmedLine`, which is the line string without parantheses. Good observation.

Comment: Yes it will. The RegEx finds the lines that correspond to `(x x x x...)`, and the `split(" ")` method takes a string and separates it at white space. Thus, it will work for any number of parameters.